# How to get array from string array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I get string array in PHP and I want convert that to array.

String Array is :

```
string(11) "[" 3"," 5","asd"]"
```

But I want something like this:

```
["3","5","asd"]
```

Tnx.

Comment: you can use `json_decode()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about casting it to **array**?

```
$string = '[" 3"," 5","asd"]';
$array = (array)$string;
print_r($array[0]);
```

**OR** with `json_decode()` function?

```
$string = '["3"," 5","asd"]';
$array = json_decode($string,1);
var_dump($array);
print_r($array);
```

**DEMO:**https://3v4l.org/ZMY6p

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using eval function.

```
$str = '[" 3"," 5","asd"]';
eval("\$arr = {$str};");
var_dump($arr);
```

However, be careful with eval since it can be exploited for bad purpose.